# How to decrease counts by passing user input from console in java and my sql

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void bookRooms(){
try{
System.out.println("Enter rooms to book ");
        int roomCount = scan.nextInt();
        String queryTwo = "select mansion_names,rent,single_rooms-1,double_rooms from mansions where mansion_names =?  ";
        // above query i am not able to pass user input roomCount from console instead number is working
        PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(queryTwo);
        ps2.setString(1, mName);
        ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
        while(rs2.next()){
            System.out.println(" "+rs2.getString(1)+" "+rs2.getInt(2)+" "+rs2.getInt(3)+" "+rs2.getInt(4));//+" "+rs.getInt(4)+" "+rs.getString(5)+" "+rs.getInt(6)+" "+rs.getInt(7));
        }
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error");
    };
}
```

in the above queryTwo i am not able to pass user input roomCount from console instead number is working just fine
is there any alternative method to pass scanner input once the number is entered as i am new in java jdbc i need senior people suggestion

Sample input and output i have added below this is working if i use below query
    "select mansion_names,rent,single_rooms-1,double_rooms from mansions where mansion_names =?  ";

```
Enter mansion name to book 
Shanthi
 mansion_names rent single_rooms double_rooms
 Shanthi 3500 3 3
Enter rooms to book 
1
 Shanthi 3500 2 3
```

I am trying to pass console input to minus from single_rooms like below it is not working

"select mansion_names,rent,single_rooms-roomCounts,double_rooms from mansions where mansion_names =?  ";

i do not have idea how to do this help me if you have suggessions i will try on my own. Thank you...!!

Comment: Don't do this at the Query level. Use that mechanism to strictly retrieve data from the database. Instead do your numerical calculations while processing the **resultset** derived from your query, for example: `.... + (rs2.getInt(3) - roomCount) + ....`. Of course you still need to add some code to determine whether it's **Single** or **Double** room(s) being booked so as to know where to subtract **roomCount** from.

Comment: Thanks for your time DevilsHnd , like you said if i use subtraction in resultset +rs2.getInt((2)-roomCount)   i am getting below error msg 
errorjava.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'Shanthi'

and leave it double rooms, i am doing it for single rooms only

Comment: is there any other way around i mean storing entire query result in java and do the calculation we like with the values DevilsHnd...?

Comment: Your first OPEN parentheses is in the wrong place. Look at the example provided in comment. The way you have it will change the index value for **.getInt()**.

Comment: To reduce confusion you should use table field names when retrieving data from your ResultSet, for example: `.... + (rs2.getInt("single_rooms") - roomCount) + ....`.

Comment: Hi DevilsHnd bro yes it is working just fine. Thanks for your support bro...